# How to close the power off system dialog, when it opens on power button long press in the lock screen. so that we can prevent our phone from switchoff

Tags: android, security, broadcastreceiver, android-security

I am working on a security app, which should recognize the power off system dialog open and close it when it's open, so that a thief can't switch off my phone.

This implementation includes recognizing power button long press and then closing the system dialog, so that there is no option for switching off the phone from lock screen.

please make sure that it's working with the latest android versions.

Thanks in advance.

i tried different methods from stack overflow, but non of them were working.